# The music playlist missing after reboot the phone, is this an Oreo issue?

Tags: android, playlist

1. Do not open the "USB debugging" menu. Than make a new playlist with aosp's music app
2. reboot the phone
3. you can find that the playlist will be missing.

i find the the playlist will be delete as the blew code:
\frameworks\base\media\java\android\media\MediaScanner.java

```
                            MediaFile.MediaFileType mediaFileType = MediaFile.getFileType(path);
                            int fileType = (mediaFileType == null ? 0 : mediaFileType.fileType);

                            if (!MediaFile.isPlayListFileType(fileType)) {
                                deleter.delete(rowId); ////// this line will delete the playlist
                                if (path.toLowerCase(Locale.US).endsWith("/.nomedia")) {
                                    deleter.flush();
```

Comment: got any solution ?? I have same issue